# Automated testing - disabling a GPS antenna

Tags: testing

I am doing automated testing on a module.

This module has a SMA connection to a GPS antenna.

I need to automatically (programmatically) disable the connection to this antenna somehow.

What would be the best way to achieve disable the connection to a GPS antenna?

Comment: how "disabled" must the connection be? will the antenna still be there?

Comment: The module needs to stop receiving data from the antenna. Ideally the antenna isn't moved.

Comment: so you want to provide GPS signal, just not thru the antenna?

Comment: Define "best". What test equipment do you have and how can the GPS antenna be accessed? E.g., do you have a test point for it on the PCB?

Answer (score 1):

Maybe with an RF switch that works in the 1.5GHz range:

https://www.minicircuits.com/WebStore/Switches.html

They do have switches available, Look for RF 1.5GHz switch SPDT. They are expensive. You'll take a attenuation hit so it won't be the same as having an antenna.

It may be simple enough to short it out with some kind of jumper, I'm not sure how much putting something like a 0.1" header on a 50Ω or 75Ω would distort the transmission line. I was thinking you would put it between signal and return not in series with the signal line.

Comment: The switch also needs to pass DC, so you'll need a pair of bias T's too. But yes, this is the correct solution.

Comment: If you just wanted to shut the signal down, you could put the DC bias injector after the switch, the antenna would still remain powered, but the signal would not reach the reciever